# 你是我的小呀小苹果儿 What is the purpose of the second 小?

Tags: meaning, usage

So I'm listening to this catchy song and the chorus goes `你是我的小呀小苹果儿`. I'm wondering why the 小 is being said twice. Is that just something the artist is doing to play with the language in the song or would you actually say that 小 two times?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzHFD1sEqpE#t=100

Comment: The usage usually appears in a song, for matching up the melody, or strenthening the (merry) mood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the same as songs in English - repetition is for rhythm.

你是我的小呀小苹果儿

You're my little - little apple

Something like that.

Comment: An example would be Emilia's Big Big World.

Answer (score 4):

See this: 我是一只小小小小鸟，想要飞呀飞　却飞也飞不高。
The purpose of the additional words is to match the rhythm. They don't make sense usually. But in some condition, the are to emphasize the feeling.
http://youtu.be/FdjR-AMz50c

Answer (score 2):

just like this in English:

You are my liiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiittle apple.

repeat for emphasize.

Answer (score 1):

小苹果 has a lively rhythm. 
The additional 小 avoids prolonging other words.

Answer (score 0):

Same as "twinkle twinkle little star..."